# Многопоточность или асинхронность для бота

Tags: python, python-3.x

как сделать многопоточку или асинхронность (ни то, ни то у меня не получилось) для бота, чтобы он отвечал более 10 пользователям сразу?

```
import vk_api, json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkEventType, VkLongPoll
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

from time import sleep, time
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread
from os.path import abspath as tdir
import threading
from datetime import datetime as date
from random import randint
import math
import re

from config1234 import tok
from gameБД import *
from photo import *

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = tok)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def check_wrd(s: str) -> bool:
    if s == s.title():
        return True
    else:
        return False
    print('text')
def get_name(uid: int) -> str:
    data = vk_session.method('users.get', {'user_ids': uid})[0]
    return "{} {}".format(data['first_name'], data['last_name'])

def worker(i):
    print(f"worker - {i}")

threads = []

for i in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(target = worker, args = (i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Вообще-то он и так должен... Если ты ограничения api не нарушаешь.

Comment: Для большинства ботов будет вполне достаточно одного-единственного синхронного потока

Comment: У меня тестеров 10 человек, а бот разговаривает только с одним